# What is the name of the web element that divided in columns and have illustrations on each column?

Tags: website-design, terminology, multi-column

Do you know the name of this kind of element that is usually used in web design?

[image]

Searching around I have a feeling that it doesn't really have a specific name, just "column design" or something. The reason I'm asking this is to have a deeper understanding on the illustration of this specific element. Illustration art in general, and website illustration art in specific are not something new, see for example [this video about illustration art](https://youtu.be/ZPQ-8Kty8X4), and [this article about illustration styles in web design](https://www.awwwards.com/30-examples-of-illustration-styles-in-web-design.html). However, in this specific element, there is not much room for details, and both those links don't emphasize this constrain at all. Illustration artists can still work on this element, but I think until we have a concept for it, it will be hard to solidify our skills.

The image below is another example on the need of concrete knowledge of this kind of illustration: it needs to carry an amount of sophistication and subtlety, while being constrained in a small amount of space (it's actually the mission of my project):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are usually referred to as cards. They may have illustrations, photos, or no image at all.

From [NN Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/cards-component/):

> A card is container for a few short, related pieces of
> information. It roughly resembles a playing card in size and shape,
> and is intended as a linked, short representation of a conceptual
> unit.

Comment: I see. Do you know how should a card be designed if it contains sophisticate information? Also, when should card *not* be used?

Comment: Couldn't they also be referred to as tiles depending on how they are used/implemented?

Comment: @MichaelLai - tiles usually have less content within each container, such as gallery views that are simply images.

Comment: @Ooker - here's an article that goes into some best practices: https://uxplanet.org/using-card-based-design-to-enhance-ux-51f965ab70cb
Specifically, if you have a large set of homogenous cards, it may be better to choose a different component, such as a list.